# Twilio Undefined Response for Received Response

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-api

I am trying to write an end point in node.js to (for now) log the body of a message sent to a Twilio number. Here is the node endpoint:

```
 app.post('/handle', twilio.webhook({validate: false}), function (req, res)    {
   var from = req.body.From;
   var smsRequest = req.body.Body;
   console.log(from);  // undefined
   console.log(smsRequest);  // undefined
   console.log(req.body);  // {}
   res.sendStatus(200);
 });
```

The function executes properly, but the request body is an empty object leading to the variables from and smsRequest being undefined. I have looked in my logs, and the messages are there with the appropriate values. Reading through the documentation and sample code it appears that req.body.From and req.body.Body are the right parameters in the request. Does anyone know what the error could be?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have body-parser installed and are you using it to [parse the request's body as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#bodyparserurlencodedoptions)? Also, do you have your `TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN` set in the environment?

Comment: What is being POSTed to your endpoint? Is it JSON? You are probably missing the bodyParser: http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.body

Comment: I was missing: app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); Thank you both